# Vaper Persistent Store ID problem associated with Fluent

Tags: vapor

**Scenario:** Using local Postgres DB via Fluent package.

**Goal:** To produce a simple DB table with two fields: 'Name' (String) and 'Info' (Data).

I'm testing the storage & retrieval of JSON Data via a Multi-Part URL Content-Type.

**Problem:**

> [ NOTICE ] Server starting on `http://127.0.0.1:8080` [ INFO ] POST
> /countries [request-id: 9482E574-87A8-41A4-BF36-C4E61FC6509C] [
> WARNING ] Value required for key at path 'id'. No value associated
> with key "id". [request-id: 9482E574-87A8-41A4-BF36-C4E61FC6509C]

I've broken the code down to the simplest form.

**The Server:**

The *decode* part is where the warning is triggered:

```swift
func create(req: Request) async throws -> Response {
    let country = try req.content.decode(PersonModel.self)
```

Here's the model on the server:

```swift
import Fluent
import Vapor

final class PersonModel: Model, Content {
    static var schema = "persons" // Set the database table name

    @ID(key: .id)
    var id: UUID?

    @Field(key: "name")
    var name: String

    @Field(key: "info")
    var info: Data

    init() {}

    init(id: UUID? = nil, name: String, info: Data) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.info = info
    }
}
```

The following is the entire client code with actual test data:

```swift
import Foundation
enum PersonData {
    static let person = """
    {
        "Name": [
            "Frederick",
            "Cabot",
            "Lee"
        ]
    ,
        "Address": [
            "901 Edgewood",
            "Ann Arbor",
            "MI",
            "48103"
        ]
    }
    """.data(using: .utf8)
}

func BuildAndSendPerson() async throws {
    let personName = "Frederick C. Lee"
    let personData = PersonData.person!

    var body = Data()
    let boundary = "Boundary-\(UUID().uuidString)"
    let serverFilesURL = URL(string: "http://localhost:8080/countries")!

    // Construct request
    var request = URLRequest(url: serverFilesURL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    // Two boundaries: 1) Person Name and 2) Person Info (Data)
    // Note: the multiple '\r\n' is necessary syntax.

    body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
    body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"name\"\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
    body.append("Content-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
    body.append("\(personName)\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
    // -----------------
    body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
    body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"info\"\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
    body.append("Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
    body.append("\(personData)\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
    // -----------------
    body.append("\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)

    // Append the final boundary
    body.append("--\(boundary)--\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)

    request.httpBody = body

    print(request)
    // Send request asynchronously]

    do {
        let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)

        if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            // Access response status code and headers
            let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode

            // Process response data
            if let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                print("Response String: \(responseString)")
            }

            // Handle different status codes as needed
            switch statusCode {
            case 200 ... 299:
                print("Success")

            case 400 ... 499:
                print("\(statusCode): Client Error")

            case 500 ... 599:
                print("Server Error")

            default:
                print("Other Status Code: \(statusCode)")
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Here's the migration code:

```
import Fluent
// You need to run this migration from the prompt.
// Remember to REGISTER you migrations!

struct CreateCountry: AsyncMigration {
    let countries = "countries"
    // Undo operation:
    func revert(on database: FluentKit.Database) async throws {
        try await database.schema(countries).delete()
    }

    // Creating the table:
    func prepare(on database: FluentKit.Database) async throws {
        print("Migration Prepare")
        try await database.schema(countries)
            .id()
            .field("title", .string, .required)
            .field("info", .data)
            .create()
    }
}
```

I'm assuming that [Vapor 4] does auto-migration every time I run the server app [>swift run].

I tried to add 'id' everywhere: the source and the receiving data model.   I still get the warning:

> [ WARNING ] Value required for key at path 'id'. No value associated
> with key "id". [request-id: 9482E574-87A8-41A4-BF36-C4E61FC6509C]

Remedy?

Comment: Can you include the Migration that creates the table as well? Also, have you tried a simple URL encoded form?

Comment: I've added the Migration code as requested.  I've tried text/plain of two sentences, one for each part.   Same 'id' issue when I attempt to decode.

Comment: Use the debugger to step into the decoding code - it looks like the decoder is failing to spot the optional ID property or it's decoding it wrong. This is the usual error when you forget to send a content type header

Comment: I dumbed down the code to merely use the text/plain content-type header.
I will build a new vapor project to see if this irritant manifests again.
I may have to douche the Fluent for being BUGGY.
I'm also looking at SwiftData to see if that can work within Vapor, and if so, can it scale well?